# Pasculli Oboe Concerto Composition Year

Tags: classical-music

Does anyone know which year the Pasculli's La Favourita oboe concerto is composed? I only know it's published in 1976.

Answer (score 4):

Pasculli's version doesn't seem quite to be the original as it is a transcription for piano. I wonder who wrote the orchestra accompaniment of the Oboe concerto.... or is it just the original version by Donizetti (1840)?

*Operatic Fantasias ANTONIO PASCULLI was among the most distinguished oboists of his generation. In 1860 he was made professor of oboe and cor anglais at the Palermo Conservatory at the age of eighteen. His phenomenal ability as a performer is displayed in the dazzling operatic fantasias he wrote for his instrument, weaving melodies of well known operas into compositions that call for challenging feats of virtuosity.*

https://www.naxos.com/catalogue/item.asp?item_code=8.570567

Antonio Pasculli (1842–1924)

**So the Oboe arrangements must have been written in the years of 1860-80**:

- 1860 Professor in Palermo
- 1884 gone blind

https://www.naxos.com/mainsite/blurbs_reviews.asp?item_code=8.570567&catNum=570567&filetype=About%20this%20Recording&language=English

Answer (score 2):

I see "Musica Rara 1879" on the sheet music PDFs I've found, including [this one on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Concerto_sopra_motivi_dell'opera_'La_favorita'_di_Donizetti_(Pasculli%2C_Antonino)).

And while a literal translation of Italian "rara" is "rare," I see that phrase already translated in some sheet music versions to "Music Edition 1879," so that would be my guess for composition or original publication date.

Comment: [Musica Rara](http://www.musicarara.com/index.php) is a London publisher of editions of rare music.